# Restrict website access during timeframe

Tags: php, .htaccess, web, webserver

I am wondering what the best to to tackle this is.

I am developing an online store which will only be open during certain hours. When a user visits any page outsite of these hours I need a to redirect to a static page.

Should this be tackled in the htaccess file? I don't want to include a php script on every page if possible?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do it:

```
Rewrite On
RewriteCond %{TIME_HOUR} ^(13|14|15)$ # blocks the shop from 1-3 pm
RewriteRule ^.*$ closed.html [F,L]
```

And always remember: Time format is 0-23!

Answer (score 3):

Below code may Help:

```
#Shows up only between 11:01:01 - 11:01:59am 
RewriteCond %{TIME_HOUR}%{TIME_MIN} >1101 [OR] 
RewriteCond %{TIME_HOUR}%{TIME_MIN} <1102 [OR]
```

Comment: Link only answers are highly discouraged. You should take the information from those links and provide the answer **here**, you can still provide those links as a "source" to your answer, but the answer should be available without following the links.